# Finding the average of double values from the command line?

Tags: java

I wrote this to get double values from the command line and average them, but it doesn't seem to be calculating. Am I supposed to initialize the array first?

```
public class Average {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double avg=0;
        double num=0;

        for (int i=0; i>=args.length; i++)
            num = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
            avg+=num;

        System.out.println(avg/args.length);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Edit: This is the finished product, I fixed the for loop by adding the curly braces and fixing the logic. The last line doesn't require a cast, but it is a good idea.

```
public class Average {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double avg=0;
        double num=0;

        for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            num = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
            avg+=num;
        }

        System.out.println(avg/args.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the curly brackets in the for statement.

Comment: I'd check to make sure length wasn't zero.

Comment: Your code is full of beginner mistakes that you need to learn how to spot and correct on your own.

Comment: No, that's C.  Java will have it as a number.

Comment: well-specified, specific question after putting in one's own effort - i wonder why downvoted. did the downvoters get downvoted when they wrote their first few programs?

Comment: -1 "_This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or **not useful** ._"  This question has almost zero chance of helping anybody in the future with its current content and title.

Comment: ... And I've had questions and answers downvoted a decade _after_ learning to program. Just because it's downvoted it doesn't mean he can't get an answer and/or learn something.  Part of downvoting is controlling how questions and answers are indexed.  It's not necessarily personal.

Comment: On the positive side, I wish all beginner programmers could put in the same effort _and_ format their code as nicely as the OP.  I predict success for him/her in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple problems here.  One is that your loop will only execute if args has length 0 (it will then crash)!  This is because the conditional in the loop is wrong.  We can make this more obvious by changing to a while loop.

```
   int i = 0;
   while (i >= args.length) i++;
```

You should change the >= to <.

Another problem is that your loop is only one statement long!  We can make this more obvious by changing the indentation to match what is going on.

```
   for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++)
        num = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
   avg+=num;
```

This can be avoided in the future by always using curly braces in your loops and conditionals:

```
   for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
        num = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
        avg+=num;
   }
```

The other potential problem is that args.length is an int, and you are using it in division with a double.  Although Java will probably do the right thing here, you are safest to explicitly cast any int to a double before using it in such a calculation.

```
    System.out.println(avg/(double)args.length);
```

Comment: yup, block-scoping is important, too. +1 for that, seanmk.

Comment: Wrong about the cast to double.  No need for that.

Comment: thanks, I didn't see the simple mistake. and the casting is a good idea as well, much appreciated

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer to also include the conditional fix.  Thanks for noticing jahroy!

Answer (score 4):

You probably meant:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
```

As this is the main logical issue here, there are other (syntactic) problems that needs to be addressed, that others have mentioned (see @seanmk's answer, for instance, on the importance of scoping loops).

*(Note: this was written before @seanmk's answer was updated with additional information, when it only regarded the issue of brackets and scoping of loops).*

Comment: it that solved your issue, please tick the answer as accepted, thanks.